# Visual basic copy html link from website (getElementsByClassName)?

Tags: html, vb.net, excel

Hi I'm new to VB and currently working with it in Excel and I'm having problems I want to go to a website then get a link from that website and then print that link.

I already know how to do the "go to the website and get the innertext by getElementsById":

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument, quote As String


Sub MsgboxTest()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

        ie.navigate "http://www.patan77.com/"


        Do
            DoEvents
            Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

            Set doc = ie.document


            quote = doc.getElementById("date").innerText



           Debug.Print quote



End Sub
```

This just gets the text (the date) from an div id if I want it to print the link that I get from going to the bottom in the page hovering over "Other Stuff" then the actual link from CinebenchEstimator:

IMG: http://www.patan77.com/screenshot/print_link_2.JPG

in this case I want it to print this: http://www.patan77.com/Cinebench_Estimator/Cinebench_Estimator.html

(I'm just using my site as an example here to show what I want to do)

I'm guessing I would need to do something like this:

```
quote = doc.getElementById("mail").getElementsByClassName("menu")(0).getElementsByTagName("ul")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")(0).getElementsByTagName("ul")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")(3).getAttribute("href")
```

but that is obviously not working, so what I'm I missing / doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that:

```
doc.getElementById("mail") _
    .getElementsByClassName("menu")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("li")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("li")(3)
```

returns a `li` element which does not have an `href` attribute to get.

You want the first child of that `li` element:

```
doc.getElementById("mail") _
    .getElementsByClassName("menu")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("li")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")(0) _
    .getElementsByTagName("li")(3) _
    .Children(0).getAttribute("href")
```

This will return the `href` of `Cinebench_Estimator/Cinebench_Estimator.html`. Prepend the URL base ("http://www.patan77.com/") and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks works great, how would I do if the first element isn't an div id but class?

Comment: You'd do it the same way you're accessing `.menu`... `doc.getElementsByClassName("whichever-class-name")(x)` where `x` is the index of the `div` you need. Alternatively, you could do it all by accessing `.Children(x).Children(x).Children(ad nauseum)`, but `class` and `id` attributes make the code less brittle and easier to read.